# apache - smart way to protect and hide admin folder? robots.txt? .htaccess? Anything else or better?

Tags: security, .htaccess, robots.txt

How do I protect and hide /adminblah/ folder from robots and from users so the only the administrator will know it exists?

1) To prohibit it from robots and bots, we can use robots.txt file.
But, that file will contain Disallow: /adminblah/ then. As result, everybody (who wants to) will know the path to the administrator's folder because he can read robots.txt file.
For that purpose, we can put .htaccess file to the /adminblah/ to password protect that folder.
Is that smart? Any smarter solutions to limit access to /adminblah/index.php page?

This question concerns all the content - admin php files, admin pictures etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mentionning the directory in robots.txt is not a solution since it's worse than doing nothing as you say it yourself.

.htaccess protection is a very good option alone ; add it at the root of /adminblah/ and even IF someone guesses it (including robots) they'll get nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Using a robots.txt to hide a directory from search engines is nothing more than [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). You must have proper access controls on the content and a .htaccess file is perfect for this.

Answer (score -3):

I like to do things like this

```
RedirectMatch permanent (?i)adminblah http://www.fbi.gov
```